# Handling mach exceptions in 64bit OS X application

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, darwin

I have been able to register my own mach port to capture mach exceptions in my applications and it works beautifully when I target 32 bit. However when I target 64 bit, my exception handler `catch_exception_raise()` gets called but the array of exception codes that is passed to the handler are 32 bits wide. This is expected in a 32 bit build but not in 64 bit.

In the case where I catch `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` the first code is the error number and the second code should be the address of the fault. Since the second code is 32 bits wide the high 32 bits of the 64 bit fault address is truncated.

I found a flag in `<mach/exception_types.h>` I can pass in `task_set_exception_ports()` called `MACH_EXCEPTION_CODES` which from looking at the Darwin sources appears to control the size of the codes passed to the handler. It looks like it is meant to be ored with the behavior passed in to `task_set_exception_ports()`.

However when I do this and trigger an exception, my mach port gets notified, I call `exc_server()` but my handler never gets called, and when the reply message is sent back to the kernel I get the default exception behavior.

I am targeting the 10.6 SDK.

I really wish apple would document this stuff better. Any one have any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if this has more to do with the kernel you're running; you'd get 32-bit exceptions under the 32-bit kernel and 64-bit exceptions under the 64-bit kernel?  The 32-bit kernel is still the default on 10.6, but if you have a new-enough Mac, you can try it...

Comment: The 32-bit kernel is fully 64-bit aware and will pass either 64-bit or 32-bit exceptions to an application. It all depends on how your app asks for, and handles them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

To handle mach exceptions, you have to register a mach port for the exceptions you are interested in. You then wait for a message to arrive on the port in another thread. When a message arrives, you call `exc_server()` whose implementation is provided by System.library. `exec_server()` takes the message that arrived and calls one of three handlers that you must provide. `catch_exception_raise()`, `catch_exception_raise_state()`, or `catch_exception_raise_state_identity()` depending on the arguments you passed to `task_set_exception_ports()`. This is how it is done for 32 bit apps.

For 64 bit apps, the 32 bit method still works but the data passed to you in your handler may be truncated to 32 bits. To get 64 bit data passed to your handlers requires a little extra work that is not very straight forward and as far as I can tell not very well documented. I stumbled onto the solution by looking at the sources for GDB.

Instead of calling `exc_server()` when a message arrives at the port, you have to call `mach_exc_server()` instead. The handlers also have to have different names as well `catch_mach_exception_raise()`, `catch_mach_exception_raise_state()`, and `catch_mach_exception_raise_state_identity()`. The parameters for the handlers are the same as their 32 bit counterparts.
The problem is that `mach_exc_server()` is not provided for you the way `exc_server()` is. To get the implementation for `mach_exc_server()` requires the use of the MIG (Mach Interface Generator) utility. MIG takes an interface definition file and generates a set of source files that include a server function that dispatches mach messages to handlers you provide. The 10.5 and 10.6 SDKs include a MIG definition file <mach_exc.defs> for the exception messages and will generate the `mach_exc_server()` function. You then include the generated source files in your project and then you are good to go.

The nice thing is that if you are targeting 10.6+ (and maybe 10.5) you can use the same exception handling for both 32 and 64 bit. Just OR the exception behavior with `MACH_EXCEPTION_CODES` when you set your exception ports. The exception codes will come through as 64 bit values but you can truncate them to 32 bits in your 32 bit build.

I took the `mach_exc.defs` file and copied it to my source directory, opened a terminal and used the command `mig -v mach_exc.defs`. This generated `mach_exc.h`, `mach_excServer.c`, and `mach_excUser.c`. I then included those files in my project, added the correct declaration for the server function in my source file and implemented my handlers. I then built my app and was good to go.

Well, this not the best description, but hopefully it helps someone else out.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only documentation i have been able to find on this.

Comment: When you have handles the original exception do you need to signal the original thread somehow, in order for it to continue? It seems to be stuck waiting..

Comment: Cheers Brad, I had the same problem and this solved it. The relevant GDB code is [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-excthread.c) for anyone interested.

Comment: @hooleyhoop you need to return `KERN_SUCCESS` from the exception handler (e.g. `catch_mach_exception_raise()`), then message the exception port back using the message buffer setup for you by `mach_exc_server()`. If you want to modify machine registers or anything else before continuing the thread you can either do it in the exception handler, or by suspending the thread (`thread_suspend()`) before messaging back the exception port, then resuming after modifications have been made.

Comment: An actual code snippet would be great, I've spent two days trying to figure out how to catch `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and print a stack trace. No luck so far.

Comment: This seems to still be fairly valid, even 8 years later. However, now there is no `mach_exc_server`, even after MIG generation. In fact, `exc_server` is now generated via the same `mig` invocation shown above. I've not quite gotten there yet, but it _seems_ like the 32/64 bit handling has been integrated and works for both cases, (by calling `exc_server`) depending on how the generated source is compiled into your program.